# memory usage history from command line in Debian

Tags: memory, debian, logging, cpu-usage

I need to know the memory/CPU usage history from command line. My server is Debian (text mode only). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the top command in batch mode by using the -b option, then dump that to a file.

On start up of your server, open a terminal, run the following commmand.

```
top -b > ~/cpu.txt
```

The sysstat collection of tools contains sar which is able to save system activity information: http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/documentation.html

Regards,
Paresh

Comment: Adding some sort by MEM options to top may help, like `top -o %MEM -b`, plus some head & tail snipping could show the top few "hogs"

Comment: @Xen2050: 
 
Why ~/ ? What is ~/ ?

Comment: That's just a shortcut meaning your user's home directory. Read `man bash` for the "Tilde Expansion" section for more info

Comment: @Xen2050, Is there a way to save in a file all information from "free" command ? I need it every 2 minutes: http://imgur.com/a/iOpIF

Comment: Or "vmstat" command

Comment: @EdS That's redirection, specifically to a file with `> file` or `>> file` to append, but can go through other programs first like head, tail, cut, etc. See their man pages for info, and Bash's man page for the "REDIRECTION" section and "Appending Redirected Output". Use a `while` or `until` loop with some `sleep 120` for delay. Or just search the web ;-)